# I need to average cells in column based on range of time, where time is in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am trying to get the averages of a column that meet certain criteria into a single cell.

tried using averageif but can't get the desired value.

Also, the time slots are in a 10 min range
like 1:10, 1:20 etc.
what if the time is 1:15 or 1:25.

Comment: How have you tried averageif, and how did the results differ from your expected value? What is your expected result if the time is 1:15 or 1:25?

Comment: Show what you did with averageif() then we may be able to correct it.

Comment: So you started recording at 02:15 and stopped at 01:45, how are you travelling back in time?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a simple method to get 30 min values:

[image]

As text to save typing:

```
IF(MOD(ROW(),3)>0,"",SUM(B3:B6)/4)
```

You can adjust this to suit what you need.

Answer (score 0):

With this formula you can get the following result:

```
=(SUM(IF((A$2:A$17>=C2)*(A$2:A$17<D2),B$2:B$17,0))+IF(C2-VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:A$17,1)>TIME(0,0,10),(1-(C2-VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$17,1))/TIME(0,10,0))*VLOOKUP(C2,A$2:B$17,2),0)-IF(D2-VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:A$17,1)>TIME(0,0,10),(1-(D2-VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:B$17,1))/TIME(0,10,0))*VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:B$17,2),0))/(D2-C2)*TIME(0,10,0)
```

[image]